# Multi Banding app with Android App

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Client one Image

[image: CLient one image]

Client two Image

[image: CLient Two]

I need to develop an app which has the same business logic. But the theme,color logo icon and Launcher icon are different based on the clients.

Now I need to build apk based on client list. I figure out that productFlavors is used.

http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/

The problem I am facing I need to create different package, res folder for each client to use productFlavors . I, dont want to create different package as well as different resource folder.

How can I achieve this??? Is there any replace tag for prefix or suffix name??

Here is the project structure.

[image: project structure]

Comment: why you dot think about setting all from your server side ??

Comment: Show your struct project and gradle file.

Comment: If it's just colour and theme, I think you can use colors.xml styles.xml to achieve this.

Comment: Its not only color and theme . Logo icon as well as launcher icon also need to change

Comment: I have added the project structure. How can I change only style , logo and launcher icon without creating new package and resources folder

Comment: @Sufian - Its not only color and theme . I also need to change the launcher icon and client logo image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: project structure]

Here is the solution I found to solve the problem.

1. Created a  new client name resource folder and changed the color.xml,launcher icon etc ....

Here is the gradle file changes

```
android{
    defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.deerwalk.healthportal"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
            productFlavors {
                    deerwalk {
                        applicationId
                        "com.abc.xyz"
                        versionName "1.0"
                    }
                    sdemo {
                        applicationId
                        "com.abc.xyz"
                        versionName "1.0"
                    }
                    tdemo {
                        applicationId
                        "com.abc.xyz"
                        versionName "1.0"
                    }
                } }
```

Android Studio does every things just we need to point to same name in color etc.

Answer (score 1):

Still, [Product Falvours](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/12/leveraging-product-flavors-in-android.html) in Android should be the good to go in your case. Its not that complex which you are thinking currently. After setting the things up it would be very helpful to maintain your each version and variants of the app.

> The problem I am facing I need to create different package, res folder
>   for each client to use productFlavors . I, dont want to create
>   different package as well as different resource folder.

AFAIK, you just need to create different package and class which are differs in logic and not need replicate all of this. Creating res folder is not that difficult as it would only one time required.

Comment: He has already mentioned this. But if you can clear his reservations about it, this might be what he's looking for.

Comment: As per the process I need to create different layout for each client. However I have the same layouts for all the clients only logo ,launcher icon and color theme is change. How can I achieve this ????

Comment: So, you can have only one layout xml file in your main res folder. and you can put different logo,launcher-icon, related images in respective flavor res folder. android would runtime fetch the respective one based on which flavor you want apk for.

Comment: @Bhavesh Patadiya Can you please show me a sample code. It will be very helpful for me .

Comment: @BhaveshPatadiya - Can you please show me a sample example??